# Why am I seeing inconsistant inaccuracies with position drivers, and can this be fixed?

Tags: error, drivers

I have an object-of-constant-width that rotates around its Z-axis, with a driver on its X-position and a driver on its Y-position that, together, should keep the object entirely located within a stationary cube as the object rotates.

However, when viewing the animation, sometimes portions of the object clip through the faces of the cube. Confusingly, this clipping is not consistent, with the degree of clipping on any given frame differing if I play through the animation at regular speed, step forward through the same frames one-by-one, or step backward through the same frames one-by-one.

Is there a way to increase the accuracy and consistency of the driver calculations?

The expressions I'm using for the drivers are below.

For the X-position:

```
((1/2)-(1/sqrt(3))*cos(((rZ) % (2/3*pi))-pi/6)) if ((rZ) % (2/3*pi)) < (1/3*pi) else ((-1/2)+(1/sqrt(3))*sin((rZ) % (2/3*pi)))
```

For the Y-position:

```
((-1/2)+(1/sqrt(3))*cos(((rZ+pi/2) % (2/3*pi))-pi/6)) if ((rZ+pi/2) % (2/3*pi)) < (1/3*pi) else ((1/2)-(1/sqrt(3))*sin((rZ+pi/2) % (2/3*pi)))
```

The input variable is `rZ`, the Z-rotation value of the object.

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ to give it a try (and be sure I do not mess your formula...) ?

Comment: I'd suspect you have a dependency loop.  Blender apparently can't separate location from rotation for calculating dependencies-- they're not perfectly granular.  You could drive both position and rotation from some other object (or a custom property) instead.

Comment: @Nathan Adding a cube object with the same rotation keys and swapping it with the OOCW in the driver dependency works perfectly!